# How do I split a string into multiple variables and remove chars not required

Tags: .net, string

I have the following string, which I need to break down into 2 main usable variables.

StreamTitle='Let's Groove - Earth Wind and Fire';StreamUrl='https://listenapi.planetradio.co.uk/api9/eventdata/86966431';

I need to split the string first at the point of the first ";", so we have

String1 = StreamTitle='Let's Groove - Earth Wind and Fire';

String2 = StreamUrl='https://listenapi.planetradio.co.uk/api9/eventdata/86966431';

I then need to remove StreamTitle=' and split the Let's Groove - Earth Wind and Fire by using the - as the split point.

Now I have managed to extract the song title and author, but I just cant seem to split the original string at the initial point (";"). I need both string1 being split into 2 and string2 kept as it is.

Can any one help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two separate regex replacements to isolate the author and song:

```cs
string input = "StreamTitle='Let's Groove - Earth Wind and Fire';StreamUrl='https://listenapi.planetradio.co.uk/api9/eventdata/86966431';";
string title = Regex.Replace(input, @"^.*?='(.*?)\s*-.*$", "$1");
string author = Regex.Replace(input, @"^.*?='.*?-\s*(.*?)';.*", "$1");
Console.WriteLine(title);   // Let's Groove
Console.WriteLine(author);  // Earth Wind and Fire
```

Comment: Thank you for your feed back. I will try that. One of the issues is that sometimes a time stamp is used like the following, StreamTitle='';StreamUrl='';UTC='20210531T114040.088'; which is constantly updating. Causing the song title to keep updating. Is there a way to store the title as a variable that no longer updates. If that makes sense.

Comment: Similar to the following StreamTitle='Years & Years - Starstruck';StreamUrl='';UTC='20210531T114900.593';

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to break down the string

```
                            Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(metadataHeader, "StreamUrl(.*)", "")
                            Dim output2 As String = Regex.Replace(output, "';", "")
                            Dim output3 As String = Regex.Replace(output2, "StreamTitle='", "") '.ToLower()
                            Dim illegalChars As Char() = "?/&.~`´,;:|@#$^*{}()[]""_<>\".ToCharArray()
                            Dim value As String = output3
                            Dim length As Integer = value.Length
                            ResultsBox.Text = output3
                            ResultsBox.Refresh()
```